# An upper bound for integer partitions with unique summands

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions, upper-lower-bounds

Let $p_\neq (n)$ be the number of all partitions of $n$ such that all summands are distinct (for example $p_\neq (6)=4$).

How do we show that $p_\neq (n) \leq e^{2\sqrt n}$?

Comment: My first thought is that the largest summand needs to be greater than  $2\sqrt n$ because the sum of all the numbers up to that is too small.  So we have $p_{\neq}(n)=\sum_{k=2\sqrt n+1}^np_{\neq}(n-k)$.  I don't know if that works but the coincidence of the exponent is promising.

Comment: Lots of information [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html)  Don't see the result you're looking for, though.